# mySQL - show latest entry each day including decimal mark and fractional part

Tags: mysql

I am recording my gas meter with a reed contact, coupled with a 1-wire counter. The according value is plotted to a MySQL database each time the value changes, and is reset each day at midnight. For evaluation purposes I´d like to get the highest (which is also the latest) value for each day. The MySQL table looks like this:

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-------+------+
| TIMESTAMP           | DEVICE  | TYPE    | EVENT           | READING  | VALUE | UNIT |
+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-------+------+
| 2015-10-16 01:51:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 4.99  | B_energy | 4.99  |      |
| 2015-10-16 01:31:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 3.99  | B_energy | 3.99  |      |
| 2015-10-16 01:11:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 2.99  | B_energy | 2.99  |      |
| 2015-10-16 00:55:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 2.00  | B_energy | 2.00  |      |
| 2015-10-16 00:41:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 1.00  | B_energy | 1.00  |      |
| 2015-10-16 00:01:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 0.00  | B_energy | 0.00  |      |
| 2015-10-15 22:33:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 66.85 | B_energy | 66.85 |      |
| 2015-10-15 22:11:04 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 65.85 | B_energy | 65.85 |      |
| 2015-10-15 21:49:03 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 64.85 | B_energy | 64.85 |      |
| 2015-10-15 21:29:03 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 63.85 | B_energy | 63.85 |      |
| 2015-10-15 21:09:03 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 62.85 | B_energy | 62.85 |      |
| 2015-10-15 20:49:03 | owc_gas | OWCOUNT | B_energy: 61.86 | B_energy | 61.86 |      |
+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-------+------+
```

With the help of some already answered questions here on stackoverflow I managed to get the latest values each day using the following query:

```
SELECT   DATE(TIMESTAMP), MAX(CAST(VALUE AS UNSIGNED))
FROM     history t
where    READING="B_energy" AND DEVICE="owc_gas"
GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
```

Unfortunately, the resulting output lacks the decimal mark and the following fractional part of the values.

```
+-----------------+------------------------------+
| DATE(TIMESTAMP) | MAX(CAST(VALUE AS UNSIGNED)) |
+-----------------+------------------------------+
| 2015-10-02      |                            8 |
| 2015-10-03      |                           17 |
| 2015-10-04      |                           15 |
| 2015-10-05      |                           11 |
| 2015-10-06      |                            6 |
| 2015-10-07      |                           10 |
| 2015-10-08      |                           14 |
| 2015-10-09      |                           16 |
| 2015-10-10      |                           22 |
| 2015-10-11      |                           37 |
| 2015-10-12      |                           51 |
| 2015-10-13      |                           65 |
| 2015-10-14      |                           63 |
| 2015-10-15      |                           66 |
| 2015-10-16      |                           47 |
+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

I tried different convert and cast functions to no avail, and I don´t understand why the query doesn´t respect the whole decimal value.

Sadly, my basic understanding of MySQL and queries in general is reached at this point. Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: Don't use `CAST` at all. Just `MAX(VALUE)`.

Comment: `UNSIGNED` is short for `UNSIGNED INTEGER`. Integers are whole numbers, they don't have fractions. `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL` datatypes have fractions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   DATE(TIMESTAMP), MAX(VALUE)
FROM     history t
where    READING="B_energy" AND DEVICE="owc_gas"
GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: unless VALUE is not a numeric data type

Comment: True, but seeing as it is intended to be a relative numeric value it /should/ be. If it isn't, it should be made a numeric type instead of over complicating the query.

Comment: I was just noticing that the question doesn't mention the data type, yes 4.99 _could_  be a numeric value but why _should_ we assume it is?

Comment: It's a fair point I do not deny it, but I would always encourage fixing the data structure. What little correctness enforcement the database can do for your data should always be taken advantage of.

Comment: I think my problem is that the data type is indeed varchar 32. That is because other devices have values like "opened" or "off". Without the cast function i get fractions, but the values i get are always smaller then 10. On days which exceed 10 the displayed value is 9.98

Comment: That is an issue. You could always add `and Value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'` to the query to only get the numbers with my query. If the non-numeric values are guaranteed not to start with a number `and Value > 0` should also meet your condition.

Answer (score 0):

With some hints that were given here I happened to find a solution. The problem is that the data type is varchar 32. That is because other devices have values like "opened" or "off".

The following query works like a charm:

```
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP), MAX(CAST(VALUE AS decimal(10,2))) FROM history t where READING="B_energy" AND DEVICE="owc_gas" GROUP BY DATE(TIMESTAMP)
```

The output finally looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| DATE(TIMESTAMP) | MAX(CAST(VALUE AS decimal(10,2))) |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
| 2015-10-02      |                              8.55 |
| 2015-10-03      |                             17.10 |
| 2015-10-04      |                             15.39 |
| 2015-10-05      |                             11.97 |
| 2015-10-06      |                              6.84 |
| 2015-10-07      |                             10.26 |
| 2015-10-08      |                             14.54 |
| 2015-10-09      |                             16.96 |
| 2015-10-10      |                             22.95 |
| 2015-10-11      |                             37.91 |
| 2015-10-12      |                             51.88 |
| 2015-10-13      |                             65.85 |
| 2015-10-14      |                             63.85 |
| 2015-10-15      |                             66.85 |
| 2015-10-16      |                             51.88 |
| 2015-10-17      |                             28.93 |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------+
```

This query is probably not the nicest, but it works for me.

Comment: I would definitely encourage fixing the db if that is possible. Storing 'Values' that are decimals mixed with state values like opened/off would not be recommended design. Glad you found a solution for your problem though!